# pygame mixer pygame error: Unable to open file 'file_location.mp3'

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I would like to play my mp3 file in a python script using the pygame.mixer module. I have a script that looks as following:

```
import pygame
from time import sleep
import os

# print(pygame.version.ver)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"sounds","my_sound.mp3"))
while True:
    my_sound.play()
    sleep(0.5)
```

running this on my windows10 Computer using powershell and python 3.10 results in the error

```
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'C:\\path\\to\\my\\file\\sounds\\my_sound.mp3'
```

I have tried installing all the newest >2.0.0 versions, but the error persists. Is there any kind of software drive that I need to have installed in order for this to work? On my old computer I had no problem using pygame.mixer like this without requiring some sort of additional initialization in my script.

Comment: @Rabbid76 `C:\\path\\to\\my_file.mp3` contains the sounds directory, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the .mp3 file into a .wav file, using any sort of online tool, and then it would work. PyGame is very picky about the file type in audio.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem, and made a function to help it. This may seem unprofessional but it will work.

```
def backslashChange(text):
    ans = ''
    temp = text.split("\\\\")
    for items in temp:
        if items == 'C:':
            ans += 'C:\\\\'
        else:
            ans += items 
            ans +='\\'
    ans = ans [:-1]
    return ans
```

It's a kludge I use till I find a more professional solution.
So change your code to this

```
def backslashChange(text):
    ans = ''
    temp = text.split("\\\\")
    for items in temp:
        if items == 'C:':
            ans += 'C:\\\\'
        else:
            ans += items 
            ans +='\\'
    ans = ans [:-1]
    return ans
import pygame
from time import sleep
import os

# print(pygame.version.ver)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(backslashChange(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"sounds","my_sound.mp3")))
while True:
    my_sound.play()
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using your code still returns the same erroe `Unable to open file 'C:\\\\Users\\mais\\Music\\yu2\\sounds\\tik.mp3'`, is the path supposed to look like this? Do you have an idea why it worked on my laptop, which also runs windows 10 like my current machine?

Comment: Sry it must be something wrong with my code, let me go find my original code and I will get back to you.

Comment: I just edited it, can you try it again?

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: same error code!,but it seems to work fine on my side

Comment: So you get the error message but the sound plays on your computer? I don't hear any sound, do you think it could be something related to my sound settings?

Comment: To confirm this, we can try adding the actual file location
`my_sound = pygame.mixer.music('C:\\Users\mais\Music\yu2\sounds\tik.mp3')`